# SharePoint 2013 search server disk upgrade suspend search service application

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, search

we are upgrading the disk space in our SharePoint 2013 dedicated search servers where indexing component is configured.

Should we keep search service application in a suspended mode with configuration Suspend-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication before upgrading file systems?

We are running the farm with VM boxes, not physical servers.

Answer (score 3):

That's not really necessary, since increasing disk doesn't effect the existing virtual disk. You can safely perform the increase without suspending the SSA.

Answer (score 2):

if you just adding the extra space on the search server then it will be easy and quick.

Just make sure, crawler is not crawling at that time.

As recommended, please test it in your lower environment.